# MS access: renamed form still uses old name when opened or referenced

Tags: ms-access, rename

I have a form in which I had a typo in the name. So, I renamed it in the navigation window with right click, rename. When opening the form, the old, wrong name with the typo is still showing in the tab. Also, if I try to reference the form with the corrected name, access tells me the form does not exist. The form displays the correct name in the navigation window, but not when opened.

Navigation Window:

[image: Navigation Window]

Tab when opened:

[image: Tab when opened]

Would be great if someone knows how to fix this. Sry for the ugly naming.

Comment: Have you done Compact & Repair?

Comment: Yup, first thing I tried . Did not change it.

Comment: BTW, it works when I reference it using the old name. But that will be very confusing down the line. The old name also shows up in the VBA navigator.

Comment: It appears you haven't changed the actual object name, but its shortcut name given in the custom group. Change grouping to object type, rename and then group.

Comment: Omg, did not know that was a thing. You're right, that works!

Comment: Do you mind posting the solution as an answer? If not, I can do it. @KostasK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working solution [given by KostasK in comment section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72741861/ms-access-renamed-form-still-uses-old-name-when-opened-or-referenced/72742576#comment128485796_72741861):

> It appears you haven't changed the actual object name, but its shortcut name given in the custom group. Change grouping to object type, rename and then group.